# Does jQuery have complete method for ajax that fires before success and error?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Does jQuery have a 'complete' method for ajax that fires before the success and error methods? I need something that runs regardless of the return code but fires before anything else does.

Comment: yes, it has........(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) find complete

Comment: That's not what I want, see below.

Comment: you have `beforeSend` and `complete` but they arn't exactly what you're looking for. Maybe `timeout` or `.ajaxStart()` will be more suited to what you're looking for.

Comment: Omega, can you describe the business need that you are trying to meet? By describing it here, it may help us come up with an alternative means to meet the need.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> complete
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });
>   An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.
>
> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

So to answer your question, there is no method that gets called right before success/fail/always callbacks.

What you can do is wrap your own method around the standard callbacks so that your code will run right before success/fail/always.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(beforeDone(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  }))
  .fail(beforeDone(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  }))
  .always(beforeDone(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  }));

function beforeDone(fn) {
    return function() {
        console.log('called before success/fail/always');

        fn.apply(fn, arguments); // call default success/fail/always callback
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a method that does what you're looking for. I provided an alternative in my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try beforeSend

```
$.ajax({
url : 'my_action',
dataType: 'script',
beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
    if(1 == 1) //just an example
    {
        xhr.abort();
    }
},
complete: function(){
    console.log('DONE');
}
```

});

Comment: I want a method that gets called after it returns but before success and error gets called.